# Stop Outlook from converting HTML to RTF

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I'm writing an add-in for Outlook 2007. Everything works fine except when I send an email in HTML format, Outlook converts it to RTF. So if the recipient opens it in eg. Thunderbird he gets a wonky looking text message instead of the nicely formatted html I sent.

```
Outlook.MailItem theMail = (Outlook.MailItem)((Outlook.Application)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application).CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
Outlook.Recipient rcp = theMail.Recipients.Add("joe blow <joe@blow.com>");
rcp.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
theMail.HTMLBody = <html composed elsewhere>
theMail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
```

How do I convince Outlook that I really do want html?

EDIT
OK - I found the problem here [at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/97456678-6c29-449e-a07a-fa8c6c27164b) I'm adding a user property

```
Outlook.UserProperty prop = theMail.UserProperties.Add("theQuoteId", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
prop.Value = quote.qid.ToString();
```

According to the article the property cannot be mapped to the mime headers and Outlook throws it into RTF.

So my next problem is to figure out how to add an unique tag to the message so I can link it to a database later. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a MIME type you need to set? In HTTP, interpretation problems often come about because a file was sent with the wrong MIME type. (I'm guessing `MailItem.BodyFormat` is this, but I hope there is something missing because it means the fix is relatively easy...)

Comment: I don't think it's a mime type - Outlook creates an rtf body and attaches it to the email.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a few years ago. In the end we fixed it with an Outlook hot fix, not a code change.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Outlook message in the Sent Items folder with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button) to see if the `UseTnef` named property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B`) is set to true.

It can be set if user properties are set on the message - since they cannot be preserved in MIME alone, Outlook sends in the RTF format (the infamous winmail.dat attachment).